# How to always call the same ServerSocket via WebService?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, outputstream, webservice-client

I would like ideas about a problem here, let me explain the situation, I have a endpoint with "java.net.ServerSocket", this service will be triggered the first time via webservice, (when this endpoint is called the clientSocket will be waiting for a connection)

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket clientSocket;

@GET
@Path("/conect")
public String conect() throws IOException { 
    
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3242);      
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // I need to save this connection to use on all other calls to any other endpoint
    ...
    ...
```

When the connection is made with the client so I need to leave this clientSocket always open, I need to save this clientSocket to be used in other calls by the webservice. Below I show an example of using an endpoint to record the user's presence.

```
@GET
@Path("/register-presence/{userId}")
public String registerPresence(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId){    
    
    ...
    ...

    OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); // I need to use the clientSocket here
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);

    writer.println("lUHXGbLOUaO4JczgkI2oXHTmuu/1Z0OYKQz6nYKyxw5xymw= ");
    writer.flush();
    
    return "ok";
}
```

This system I'm mounting will use this clientSocket to perform various actions when calls are made to some endpoints.

The main problem is that I need to make the connection, and after connected I need to save this connection performed to be used other times by the webService.

The connection saved to clientSocket must be available for as long as the connection is active. And the ClientSocket will be used in all the various calls that will be made by several different devices. This is the problem i do not know how to solve hehe. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to make `clientSocket` "global" or "shared enough" so that all future incoming client-connections can access it, or that it is accessible, but using it "doesn't work" in some way?

Comment: @TripeHound, So, I need to make the ClientSocket accessible always, but only within this webService... When the connection is made to the client I need to leave this clientSocket open to be used always, regardless of which device is calling the service, I do not want to connect each independent user, I need each user who calls the service to use the same clientSocket to perform the actions.